# Image not visible in email body for MSCRM 2011

Tags: email, dynamics-crm-2011

I am using email router to send emails for CRM 2011. I have created an Email template. In this email record, i have pasted an image embedded and static text content:

[image]

I used this tutorial to embedded images:
https://sliong.wordpress.com/2013/06/20/crm-2011-insert-image-to-email/

This email template gets saved in CRM but when i sent that email to an address mail like gmail/hotmail/Yahoo, the static content is displayed properly but the image in the email record is shown as "X" icon in the email body of email:

[image]

Could you please help me in letting me know what setting needs to be done at CRM side or anywhere else so that the image is shown correctly in the email sent.

I m using Dynamics crm 2011 OnPremise Rollup 15.
Please help, 
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Check if you can access the src attribute of the `<img>` element or if it is well formatted in the email. Usually that "X" means:

- The url is not resolvable
- Some email providers block images by default too
- Image url might be also blocked by a proxy